# Detect attachShadow event

Tags: javascript, events, dom, shadow-dom, mutation-observers

I'd like to detect an event of attaching shadow to the host element.

Use-case: using `MutationObserver` to watch any DOM changes and post-process the changed content as part of binding (tying) framework's logic.

Why do I need to detect this event? In order to be able to watch for a changes within the shadowDOM, another `MutationObserver` should be created and set on the shadowRoot - this works just fine, so the only issue is with detecting newly created shadows.

Needless to say, that plainly `MutationObserver` does not detect `attachShadow` action, tried that with all of the options flags set to true.

Note: I'm aware of [this question on this forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377933/how-to-detect-when-an-custom-elements-is-transcluded-into-a-shadow-tree#), yet it's not exactly the same problem, IMHO.

UPDATE:

I'm marking the answer of @Supersharp as the answer to the question, since looks like **proxifying** the native `attachShadow` method is **currently the only way** to observe this action.

Yet, similarly to the fact that we are not proxifying `appendChild`, `removeChild`, `innerHTML`/`textContent` and others, but relaying on well defined `MutationObserver` APIs, in this case too, there must be a way to achieve the same without potentially breaking native API behavior or catching up and plumbering any other possible future way to attach shadow (and probably there will be removal too?, already there is an override) etc.

I've issued a proposal to support `attachShadow` by `MutationObserver` [here](https://github.com/w3c/dom/issues/119).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could override the native `attachShadow()` method defined in the `HTMLElement` prototype.

Then, inside the new function, add a MutationObserver to the shadow root.

```js
var attachShadow = HTMLElement.prototype.attachShadow

HTMLElement.prototype.attachShadow = function ( option )
{
  var sh = attachShadow.call( this, option )
  console.info( '%s shadow attached to %s', option.mode, this )
  //add a MutationObserver here
  return sh
}

target.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
  .innerHTML = 'Hello'
```

```html
<div id=target></div>
```

Comment: It solves the problem, yet this approach seems to me more like a hack from the times of frameworks like Prototype/Backbone of many years ago.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it when using classes

```js
const Mixin = base => class extends base {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  
  attachShadow(options) {
    super.attachShadow(options);
    console.log('shadowRoot created');
  }
}

class SomeElement extends Mixin(HTMLElement) {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  
  connectedCallback() {
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = '<slot></slot>';
  }
}
customElements.define('some-element', SomeElement)
```

```html
<some-element><h1>shadow</h1></some-element>
```

Answer (score 0):

const target = document.querySelector('html-element'); //element to which shadowroot is attached
const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true }; 
const callback = function(mutationList, observer){ 
//do something
}; 
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback); 
observer.observe(target,config);

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: I think this answer misses the question and provides a way to detect changes, well, not even within the `shadowRoot` but in the element's light DOM, which is obvious. The OP is not about this, but about detection of the very fact of calling `attachShadow` method.